# Revocate a CA certificate with OpenSSL

Tags: python, openssl, certificate, x509certificate

Python newbie here! As the title implies it, I am looking for a way to revoke a CA certificate from its serial number.

I would like to achieve this by using pyopenssl's library (OpenSSL.crypto). Using this library makes loading certificates a dream come true. But revoking them is a different story altogether.

Here is what I tried:

```
import OpenSSL.crypto as crypto

def revoke_certificate(self, serial):
    crl = crypto.CRL()

    try:
        if not serial == self.get_ca_certificate().get_serial()
            filename = self.get_certificate_filename(serial)

            with open(filename, "r") as certificate_file:
                certificate_text = certificate_file.read()
                certificate = cr.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, certificate_text)
                # Note: the certificate is type X509, so it gets properly loaded
                # So... this is not going to work
                crl.set_revoked(certificate)

            # irrelevant lines of code
            # ...
    except CustomError, e:
            # irrelevant logging lines of code
            # ...

    revoked = crl.get_revoked() 
    # obviously, revoked is going to be None
    revoked.set_serial(serial)
    now = self.get_current_time()
    revoked.set_rev_date(now)

    # the rest is also irrelevant
    # ...
    # ...
```

For those who are wondering, the serial number is indeed an integer, not a `None` object.

I took the irrelevant lines of code off (have nothing to with the revocation).
I am well aware that `revoked = crl.get_revoked()` will make `revoked` a `None` object.

Any ideas as to how I could `set_revoked` a `OpenSSL.crypto.Revoked` object? Is it possible to do so from a the `certificate` (from the `with` block)? Since this `certificate` object is a `OpenSSL.crypto.X509` object, it cannot be *type-casted* as a `OpenSSL.crypto.Revoked` object.

Thanks your help